# app.CreatePerOwinContext and sharing the db context

Tags: c#, unity-container, identity

Identity requires me to use this to create a db context:

```
app.CreatePerOwinContext(EFDbContext.Create);
```

So I need to get the Microsoft Unity IOC correct.

The issue I was coming across was that I had accidently made 2 database contexts. One for everything else in my application and one for the user stuff. I started writing functions for the user stuff under the wrong context and made it throw errors.

So I decided to use a lifetime manager for my EFDbContext:

```
// Database context

container.RegisterType<EFDbContext>(new PerThreadLifetimeManager());

// Microsoft identity stuff

container.RegisterType<ApplicationSignInManager>();
container.RegisterType<ApplicationUserManager>();
container.RegisterType<IAuthenticationManager>(
    new InjectionFactory(c => HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication));
container.RegisterType<IUserStore<ApplicationUser>, UserStore<ApplicationUser>>(
    new InjectionConstructor(typeof(EFDbContext)));
```

I am wondering if this will cause issues in the future?

**Edit:**

I found out that the asynchronous stuff in Identity might have been causing an issue with this set up...

I have now used `HierarchicalLifetimeManager`, it reads like the kind of thing I need... Still unsure if i'm going to come across any issues?

Answer (score 1):

you should be ok - when you do a Resolve or ResolveAll to get the object back from the container and when you are set on using PerThreadLifeTimeManager then Unity will return the same instance for that thread. So unless you are doing multithreaded apps, then you should be fine.

ref: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660872(v=pandp.20).aspx

Comment: Ah, just found odd errors occurring and realised it's because the identity stuff uses lots of asynchronous calls. Would this interfere with that thread you were talking about?

Comment: HierarchicalLifetimeManager seems to be working... any negatives on this?

Answer (score 1):

I found this article which seemed to do exactly what was needed:

http://www.wiktorzychla.com/2013/03/unity-and-http-per-request-lifetime.html

It has a request lifetime instead of thread or container... I was noticing odd problems when using hierarchical and this second one seems to work a charm!